# Nodejs passing objects from master to workers

Tags: node.js, couchbase

How can I pass objects like Couchbase buckets or MongoDB connection objects from a Master to workers using the NodeJS cluster module?

I have read that the cluster module serialises/deserialises the message to the workers. I am trying to not create a couchbase bucket object everytime for a worker when the worker needs to read/write to Couchbase

Comment: Does each worker only process a single operation? If they live longer than that, why not just cache the connection objects?

Comment: HI Matthew, I apologize for being late in my reply. Would Redis be a good option to cache an object like a connection object? Or would some  'in memory' cache work just as well? Like memcached or node-cache module?

Comment: I think you've got a chicken-and-egg there. Where would you store the Redis connecton object?